# How to make WebView Thread safe in Awesomium

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, webview

I am not able to make safe thread webview. I have no idea how to make it 
below is my code if anyone having idea please help me.

```
 Imports System.Threading
 Imports Awesomium.Core
 Imports Awesomium.Windows.Forms

Public Class Form1
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim obj As New Object
Dim webViews As WebView() = New WebView(3) {}
Dim session = WebCore.CreateWebSession(New WebPreferences())

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    webViews(0) = WebCore.CreateWebView(1024, 800, session)
    webViews(1) = WebCore.CreateWebView(1024, 800, session)
    webViews(2) = WebCore.CreateWebView(1024, 800, session)
    Dim dictThread As New Dictionary(Of String, Thread)
    For i As Integer = 0 To 3
        dictThread.Add("Thread" & i.ToString, New Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf Webvw)))
        dictThread("Thread" & i.ToString).Name = "thread" & i.ToString
        dictThread("Thread" & i.ToString).Start(i)

    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Webvw(webviewNo As Integer)
    SyncLock obj

        webViews(webviewNo).Source = New Uri("https://www.facebook.com")
        i += 1
    End SyncLock
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Side comment: Awesomium is pretty outdated and is equivalent to Chrome 18. I would encourage you to use one of there libraries: CefGlue, CefSharp, ChromiumFx.